yosys + abc でCNFを生成しようとすると最適化されてしまってトリビアルなCNFが生成されてしまう。
SAT Solverで充足不能性を示すのが難しいCNFを作ろうとしています。
充足不能性を示すのが難しいCNFの例として鳩ノ巣原理があります。
鳩ノ巣原理はn+1羽の鳩とn個の鳩ノ巣があった時、次の2つを同時に満たすことはできないという命題です。

すべての鳩はいずれかの鳩ノ巣に入る。
それぞれの鳩の巣には鳩は高々１羽しか入っていない。

CDCL(conflict-driven clause learning)のみに基づくSAT Solverは鳩ノ巣原理を多項式時間で証明できないことが知られています。
しかし、SDCL(satisfaction-driven clause learning)に基づくSAT Solverは鳩ノ巣原理を多項式時間で（びっくりするほど速いです）証明してしまいます。
私はSDCLに基づくSAT Solverでも解くのが難しいと思われるCNFとして次のようなものを考えました。
n-bitの自然数xは次の２つを同時に満たすことはできない。

xは素数である。
xは合成数である。

私はこの命題をprime and composite tautologyと名付けました。
このようなCNFを作ろうとしています。
xが素数である証拠にはこの理論を使いました。
まともにCNFを直接組むのはむずかしいのでyosys 0.9 (git sha1 1979e0b)とをabc 1.01 というツールを使うことにしました。
私の書いたコードはこのようになります。
しかしここで問題があって、yosysが最適化をかけてしまって生成されるCNFがトリビアルに充足不能なものになってしまいます。
yosysに最適化をかけさせないで意味のあるCNFを生成させるにはどうしたらいいでしょうか？

回答が付かないので英語版stack overflow にマルチポストしたいのですが、やはりマナー違反でしょうか？向こうのポストであらかじめマルチポストであることを断っておけば大丈夫ですか？
